# Returning Search from HTML Search Bar

Tags: html

I have created this nifty little search bar above one of my table in HTML:

```
<div>
        <form name="search" class="form-search" method="get">
            <input type="text" class="search-query input-large" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The search bar appears and I am able to search, but nothing is being returned.

If someone could point me in the right direction to be able to search an entire (better yet, multiple) HTML page(s) with this search bar, I would be thankful.

Am I right in thinking I need to implement some sort of web form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add method on the button something like that:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("your input bar id").placeholder;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: and then the method would be some javascript that tells the function to - say - highlight what I searched?

Comment: It shouldn't work. It just an idea how you should do. It depends what exactly you wan't so search, some text in the body or what?

Comment: any help? Still lost!

Comment: still no help here?! @vytautas